# React Native Navigator : Show navigation bar on certain components only

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have a component that renders a Navigator :

```
render() {
    return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Navigator
        style={{backgroundColor: '#31BC72'}}
            initialRoute={Home.route()}
            renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                return React.createElement(route.component, _.extend({navigator: navigator}, route.passProps));
            }}
            configureScene={() => {
          return {
            ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
            defaultTransitionVelocity: 10000,
            gestures: {}
          };
        }} />
    </View>
    );
}
```

That's what it looks like :

[image: basic navigator component]

When I push a new route, let's say from the Home component, it looks like this :

[image: component that needs a navigation bar]

I'd like to have on this component only a navigation bar with only the back button. I can't figure how to do that..